# Accessing a child method from the main method

Tags: java

Say I have a class called Farm

```java
public class Farm extends java.lang.Object implements java.lang.Comparable<Farm>{
```

Farm consists of an array of animals on the farm. I want to see how many pigs are on the farm.

So, we have

```java
public class Pig extends Animal{
    public double getPigCount(){
       return pigCount;
    }
```

How exactly would I be able to get my pig count within my Farm class?

```java
public class Farm extends java.lang.Object implements java.lang.Comparable<Farm>{

    public String HowMany(){
        String newString += "There are " _____ + " pigs on the farm" + "\n"; 
        String newString +=" There are "____ + " cows on the farm"......etc
        return newString;
    }
```

I want to access the child method inside the main method, but I'm not sure how to exactly do this.

Comment: `getPigCount()` is not `static`, which means it is an *instance method* rather than a class method. Calling `getPigCount()` then requires an instance of `Pig`, which does not make sense anyway: why would you want to call `getPigCount()` on a particular pig?

Comment: You can remove `extends java.lang.Object` because ["every class has `Object` as a superclass."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) Every class with no explicit superclass implicitly extend `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: "There are ... on the farm." Are you trying to count how many of a type have been instantiated, or how many have been added to the farm?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static map in Animal class which stores the type of animal as key and the number of the animals created as values.

Whenever you create an instance of any animal, you increment its count in map from the constructor of each animal.

```
public abstract class Animal {

static HashMap<String, Integer> babies = new HashMap<>();

public static String howMany() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

        for (Entry<String, Integer> e : babies.entrySet()) {
            sb.append("There are " + e.getValue() + " " + e.getKey() + " on the farm.\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Below are classes of three species of animals with their constructors incrementing their count in `babies`

```
class Pig extends Animal {

    public static final String ID = "Pigs";

    public Pig() {
        Animal.babies.put(ID, babies.containsKey(ID) ? babies.get(ID) + 1 : 1);
    }

}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public static final String ID = "Dogs";

    public Dog() {
        Animal.babies.put(ID, babies.containsKey(ID) ? babies.get(ID) + 1 : 1);
    }
}

class Cow extends Animal {
    public static final String ID = "Cows";

    public Cow() {
        Animal.babies.put(ID, babies.containsKey(ID) ? babies.get(ID) + 1 : 1);
    }
}
```

Finally I test the code with some numbers

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Going to create 3 dogs, 4 pigs, and 5 cows
        int d = 3, p = 4, c = 5;
        while (d-- > 0) {
            Dog tempD = new Dog();
        }
        while (p-- > 0) {
            Pig tempP = new Pig();
        }

        while (c-- > 0) {
            Cow tempC = new Cow();
        }

        System.out.println(Animal.howMany());
    }
```

Here is my result :

```
There are 4 Pigs on the farm.
There are 3 Dogs on the farm.
There are 5 Cows on the farm.
```

Answer (score 0):

declare Pig, Cow member variable in Farm class.
And All class extends java.lang.Object.
So you don't need to extends Object.

Comment: how would I declare the pigs and cow members in the Farm class? the thing is the Farm class just adds an animal inside. it seems that the pig and cows cannot be accessed from Farm.

Comment: the thing is that java.lang.Comparable<Farm> doesnt extend to the Animal class